# How to make slideshow for images and text using viewflipper from json

Tags: android, json, viewflipper

//mainactivity.xml

```
<ViewFlipper 
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="279dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="Event Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Venue, Date"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:src="@drawable/demo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Event of the Week" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ViewFlipper>
```

I want to implement slideshow for both images and text for the above layout. And the values are from my server using json. How can i implement this. I am stuck here. does any body knows the answer.

Any body have reference link..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the basic process you'll want to follow.

**1. Download JSON data**: You'll need to use a background thread and an HTTP client to do this. Perhaps [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)and [DefaultHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html)

**2. Parse JSON data:** Once you have download the JSON you'll need to create [JSONObjects](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) and parse them into data model classes to store the data. Your model class might look something like this:

```
public class SlideshowImage {
    public String text;
    public String imageUrl;
}
```

Ideally you will end up with a `List` of SlideshowImages from the JSON.

**3. Store the Data if needed (optional):** If you want to store these model classes in a datbase that can also be done. It may not be needed however if you intend to load this information live every time.

**4 Use the list of 'SlideshowImages' to populate your view:** Finally you can access the SlideshowImage classes to load the data into each of your TextView and ImageViews.

```
SlideshowImage model = slideshowImageList.get(0);
textView1.setText(model.text);
```

You'll also need to download the imageUrls to get `Bitmap`s so you can setup your ImageViews. You should refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android) question for help with that.